# Is "reaction center" the same as "photosystem"?

Tags: cell-biology, botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

I have a diagram which labelled a part of PSI (Photosystem I) as *"reaction center"*. But I have read on several websites that the reaction centers are PSI (the whole complex, not just a part of it) and PSII.

So, which one is correct? And if the reaction center is only a part of these PSI and II complexes, what does it contain? And what does it do?

Answer (score 2):

Reaction centers are specific sites within the photosystems where the adsorbed photon energy is transferred to electrons.

Answer (score 2):

"Photosystem" and "Reaction center" are **not** synonyms​.

According to Lodish (2000):

> The absorption of light energy and its conversion into chemical energy occurs in multiprotein complexes, called *photosystems*, located in the thylakoid membrane. A photosystem has **two closely linked components**, an antenna containing light-absorbing pigments and a reaction center comprising a complex of proteins and two chlorophyll a molecules. (emphasis mine)

And according to Alberts (2002):

> Multiprotein complexes called photosystems catalyze the conversion of the light energy captured in excited chlorophyll molecules to useful forms. A photosystem consists of **two closely linked components**: an antenna complex, consisting of a large set of pigment molecules that capture light energy and feed it to the reaction center; and a photochemical reaction center, consisting of a complex of proteins and chlorophyll molecules that enable light energy to be converted into chemical energy. (emphasis mine)

Therefore, a photosystem is composed by:

1. The antenna complex;
2. The reaction center.

Here is a figure from Alberts (2002):

[image]

<sup>**Figure**: The antenna complex is a collector of light energy in the form of excited electrons. The energy of the excited electrons is funneled, through a series of resonance energy transfers, to a special pair of chlorophyll molecules in the photochemical reaction center. The reaction center then produces a high-energy electron that can be passed rapidly to the electron-transport chain in the thylakoid membrane, via a quinone.</sup>

Thus, in conclusion, the reaction center is *part of* the photosystem.

PS: Both quoted texts answer your second question (*"And if the reaction center is only a part of these PSI and II complexes, what does it contain? And what does it do?"*).

Sources:

- [Lodish, H. (2000). Molecular cell biology. 4th ed. New York: Worth Publ](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21598/).
- [Alberts, B. (2002). Molecular biology of the cell. 4th ed. New York: Garland Science](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26819/).